# libreoffice writer python script to set view layout columns

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

For text documents in LO writer I want a shortcut to toggle the view between 1 and 2 columns. To that end, I recorded two macros --  which had no effect -- so I'm trying with Python.

The Writer Menu.View.Zoom.Zoom menu item opens the `Zoom and View Layout` dialog. That dialog offers two panels: *Zoom* and *View Layout*

In a Python script we can access `current_controller.view_settings.ZoomValue` and `...ZoomType` but I don't find a way to the `View Layout` values.

In the LO user config file `registrymodifications.xcu` we have these three lines:

```
 <item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Writer/Layout/Zoom"><prop oor:name="Type" oor:op="fuse"><value>0</value></prop></item>
 <item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Writer/Layout/Zoom"><prop oor:name="Value" oor:op="fuse"><value>120</value></prop></item>
 
 <item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Writer/Layout/ViewLayout"><prop oor:name="Columns" oor:op="fuse"><value>1</value></prop></item>
```

Notice that the two zoom values are at the same level under `Layout` accessed in script directly through view_settings (see above). At that same level we have ViewLayout but in a script I have found no way of accessing what I would like to be `view_settings.ViewLayout` or view_settings.getProperty(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't learned to use Python to control LO, but it should be possible to call the Dispatcher. I recorded a macro, but didn't find the ViewLayout being modified. Looking at information you provided, I came up with this, which worked to change to 3 columns.

```basic
sub ViewLayout_3Col
    rem -----------------------------------------------
    rem define variables
    dim document   as object
    dim dispatcher as object
    rem -----------------------------------------------
    rem get access to the document
    document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
    
    rem ----------------------------------------------
    dim args2(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args2(0).Name = "ViewLayout.Columns"
    args2(0).Value = 3
    
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ViewLayout", "", 0, args2())
end sub
```